# Address out of bound error in File pointer

Tags: glibc, libc

We are observing SIGABORT while reading a stream from File pointer which is returned from popen(). File pointer wasn't NULL. But reading File pointer results in a crash.

My Code -:

```
    if ((fp = popen(cmd, "r")) == NULL) {
        LOG_FWDL(FW_UNEXP,
            "run_rsh_cmd(): Fail to run command %s (%s)\n",
            cmd, strerror(errno));
        /* reset the uid */
        if (o_uid != 0) {
            ret = setreuid(o_uid, o_euid);
            VVERIFY1(ret == 0, errno);
        }   
        return (-1);
    }   

    fscanf(fp, "%s", out); // getting signal abort here
```

backtrace

```
"Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
[New process 3593]
[New process 3638]
[New process 3594]
[New process 3595]
#0  0x0df1c0b4 in read () from ./lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0df1c0b4 in read () from ./lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x0dec400c in _IO_new_file_underflow (fp=0x1028dbe8) at fileops.c:603
#2  0x0dec4eec in _IO_default_uflow (fp=<value optimized out>) at genops.c:440
#3  0x0dec6e28 in *__GI___uflow (fp=0x1028dbe8) at genops.c:394
#4  0x0dea3288 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=0x1028dbe8, format=<value optimized out>, argptr=0x3fa6bdf8, errp=0x0) at vfscanf.c:597
#5  0x0dea73a0 in ___vfscanf (s=<value optimized out>, format=<value optimized out>, argptr=<value optimized out>) at vfscanf.c:2909
#6  0x0dea7424 in __fscanf (stream=<value optimized out>, format=<value optimized out>) at fscanf.c:32
#7  0x0e18e6dc in run_rsh_cmd (in=0xe199288 "/sbin/bootenv BadRootDev", out=0x3fa6d640 "") at upgrade_err.c:141
#8  0x0e192348 in fup_retrieve (slot=2, vi=0x3fa6db88, de=<value optimized out>) at upgrade_ipc.c:75
#9  0x100791bc in showFOSVersion (request=0x3fa74f28) at FileXfer.c:1059
#10 0x10041da0 in Switch_doGet (request=0x3fa74f28) at Switch.c:1617
#11 0x10023aa8 in dispatcher (request=0x3fa74f28) at dispatcher.c:1408
#12 0x100198f4 in main (argc=<value optimized out>, argv=<value optimized out>) at weblinker.c:809
(gdb) p *fp
No symbol "fp" in current context.
(gdb) f 7 
#7  0x0e18e6dc in run_rsh_cmd (in=0xe199288 "/sbin/bootenv BadRootDev", out=0x3fa6d640 "") at upgrade_err.c:141
141         fscanf(fp, "%s", out);
(gdb) p *fp
$1 = {_flags = -72539000, _IO_read_ptr = 0x1ec84000 <Address 0x1ec84000 out of bounds>, _IO_read_end = 0x1ec84000 <Address 0x1ec84000 out of bounds>, 
  _IO_read_base = 0x1ec84000 <Address 0x1ec84000 out of bounds>, _IO_write_base = 0x1ec84000 <Address 0x1ec84000 out of bounds>, 
  _IO_write_ptr = 0x1ec84000 <Address 0x1ec84000 out of bounds>, _IO_write_end = 0x1ec84000 <Address 0x1ec84000 out of bounds>, 
  _IO_buf_base = 0x1ec84000 <Address 0x1ec84000 out of bounds>, _IO_buf_end = 0x1ec85000 <Address 0x1ec85000 out of bounds>, _IO_save_base = 0x0, 
  _IO_backup_base = 0x0, _IO_save_end = 0x0, _markers = 0x0, _chain = 0xdfb5498, _fileno = 162, _flags2 = 0, _old_offset = 0, _cur_column = 0, 
  _vtable_offset = 0 '\0', _shortbuf = "", _lock = 0x1028dc90, _offset = -1, __pad1 = 0x0, __pad2 = 0x0, __pad3 = 0x0, __pad4 = 0x0, __pad5 = 0, _mode = -1, 
  _unused2 = '\0' <repeats 19 times>, "\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000x\000\000\000\020\020&îX\000\000\000"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> We are observing SIGABORT while reading a stream from File pointer which is returned from popen().

It looks like you are mis-interpreting what you see.

You've truncated your GDB session, but we can clearly see that the program you are debugging has *not* received `SIGABRT` -- it's merely blocked in a `read` system call.

Some *other* program (not the one you are debugging) *has* aborted, and something (probably not your program) has `wait(2)`ed for it, and printed the `Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.` message.